# TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I know that other questions with the same error have been answered, but I try the solutions and they don't work at all. I have a simple port scanner, but I get this error:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Dark/IdeaProjects/port/scanner.py", line 16, in scan
    result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not int
```

The code I have so far is:

```
from threading import Thread
import socket
host = int(eval(input('host > ')))
from_port = int(eval(input('start scan from port > ')))
to_port = int(eval(input('finish scan to port > ')))
counting_open = []
counting_close = []
threads = []

def scan(port):
    s = socket.socket()
    result = s.connect_ex((host,port))
    print(('working on port > '+(str(port))))
    if result == 0:
        counting_open.append(port)
        #print((str(port))+' -> open')
        s.close()
    else:
        counting_close.append(port)
        #print((str(port))+' -> close')
        s.close()

for i in range(from_port, to_port+1):
    t = Thread(target=scan, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

[x.join() for x in threads]

print(counting_open)
```

What does the error mean in this case and how do I fix it? Please don't refer me to the other questions, I have already read them!

Comment: In general, it is helpful to use `print(repr(...))` to find out what a variable contains. That in combination with reading the docs for `connect_ex()` shows that `host` shouldn't be an integer.

Comment: Why are you calling `int()` on the host input?  How can a hostname possibly be an integer?

Comment: And why are you calling `eval()` at all?

Comment: @JohnGordon I used 2to3 on this script and it added eval(), not sure what it does.